# Irreducible polynomials and poving the ring of intergers is a PID

Tags: field-theory, algebraic-number-theory

My question isn't too hard I think I'm just a little stumped on how to tackle the second part.

$ Let \ K=\Bbb Q(\alpha)$ where $\alpha$ is a root of $f(x)=x^3+2x+1$

1) Show that $f(x)$ is irreducible over $\Bbb Q $ and find and integral basis for $O_k$ the ring of integers.

This part i feel is ok, I can use the Mod p irreducibility test to show that $f(x)$ is irreducible with p=3 
Then from the book Introductory Algebraic Number Theory by Alaca and Williams 
We us theorems 7.1.8 and 7.1.10 to get the discriminant of $f(x)$ which is -91 which is sqaure free and thus our integral basis for $O_k$ is ${ 1, \alpha, \alpha^2 } $

2) Asks me to verfiy that $O_k$ is a PID.  Using Wold-ram-alpha we can see that the vaule  $\alpha$  takes it quite large and messy, so how do I find out my ring of intergers and hence prove it is a PID??
Thanks

Comment: Checking that a ring of integers is a PID might be very hard without Minkowsi theory. Can you use the fact that $\frac{2}{\pi}\sqrt{|-91|} =6.07...$?

Comment: then just continue with the thoery and show that f(x) does not factorise modulo p for an p less the 6?

Comment: Yes: this is what you need to do. And I think that this is quite easy to check.